# odbc_connect() on CentOS 6

Tags: php, odbc

I am currently having issues getting odbc_connect to work on my CentOS server. I have installed the Easysoft ODBC-SQL-Server driver with the aim to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

I am getting the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function odbc_connect()

When using `odbc_connect()`.

```
> ls /etc/php.d
> curl.ini      json.ini  pdo.ini       pdo_sqlite.ini  sqlite3.ini
> fileinfo.ini  odbc.ini  pdo_odbc.ini  phar.ini        zip.ini
> cat pdo_odbc.ini ; 
> Enable pdo_odbc
> extension module extension=pdo_odbc.so
```

I have installed the package php-odbc and restarted my server, is there anything else I need to do to make sure PHP has access to the odbc methods?

**UPDATES**

```
php --ini
```

points to

> /usr/local/lib/php.ini

Which doesnt have any mention of ODBC.

Running the command"

```
php -i |grep ini
```

gives:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
init_command_executed_count => 0
init_command_failed_count => 0
com_init_db => 0
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException
open sourced by => Epinions.com
```

The command

```
nm /usr/local/bin/php |grep odbc
```

gives no output.

Comment: In your `phpinfo()`, is CURL listed? Or PHAR?

Comment: Both seem to be listed yes

Comment: You should include the info from your various comments in your answer. It sounds like you have a non-package version of PHP installed for some reason. It will not work with package version of extensions. You need to either install the package PHP or manually install the ODBC extension.

Comment: Is your app web-based or command-line-based?  On some PHP installations CLI PHP config path will be different from Apache PHP.  Which CentOS version are you using and which PHP packages are installed?

Comment: Why did you install PHP from source into `/usr/local`? Was there a reason you couldn't just `yum install php`?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you are working on the right php config.

run the following command to know the right odbc ini file

```
php --ini
```

Comment: php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: try to see if your extension is enabled inside /usr/local/lib/php.ini ?

Comment: the file has no mention of odbc

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed the package php5-odbc  ?

Answer (score 3):

Double check that there's a ini file in `/etc/php.d`. It should look something like `20-odbc.ini` and should point to the `.so` file

Comment: please see the end of my post `I have installed the package php-odbc and restarted my server, is there anything else I need to do to make sure PHP has access to the odbc methods?`

Comment: @ZacPowell Sorry bout that. Updated my answer

Comment: I have updated the question with details of /etc/php.d

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the php.d directory is the correct one. If you run this

```
php -i|grep php.d
```

Does everything point to `/etc/php.d` or is there another `php` configuration location. On Centos 6 it's common to see versions of PHP that have been installed to replace the one that comes bundled with it because it's obsolete, the new version could be installed anywhere, quite often in `/opt/rh/php[version num here]`. Any additional packages installed using Yum likely won't reference the new PHP if that's what's being referenced on command line.

If thats not showing any output what does this show...

```
php -i |grep ini
```

This should give you the location of the php.ini file it's using. If it's not in

```
/etc/php.ini
```

Someone has locally installed php. You should also see a line like

```
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d
```

This will show you were it's looking for things like odbc. Find the PHP binary ie

```
which php
```

then run this on it

```
nm /usr/local/bin/php |grep odbc
```

If this gives you a lot of symbols with odbc in the name then php was compiled with odbc support, if it doesn't then odbc is not supported by that PHP binary.

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini